# Add external .ASPX pages to DotNetNuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

How can I add custom .ASPX pages to a DotNetNuke site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding any aspx page in dotnetnuke should work ok provided it is inherited from `DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase` instead of `System.Web.UI.Page`. It will work as expected. If you are using an aspx page without code behind use it like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase" %>
```

if you are using aspx page with code behind, use it like following:
(vb.net)

```
Public Class CustomAspnetPage
    DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase
```

This applies to any version of dotnetnuke.

Comment: can you please give examples when adding aspx page might be needed? thnks.

Comment: In most of the scenarios, you don't need separate aspx page. I built a wedding web site provider web site through dotnetnuke and used the aspx pages in check out process through ccavenue. I was already having those pages in aspx, so I just changed the base class and that allowed to re-use all those pages integrated into dotnetnuke.

Answer (score 2):

While you can simply add an .aspx page and in most situations it will just work.  It is probably not the "right" thing to do.  If you are trying to write code that works within the DNN framework you probably want to build a module.  Modules are built from user controls (.ascx).  Writing a .aspx page is typically reserved for situations where most or all of the functionality is independent of the DNN framework, but still part of a DNN website.

There are many tutorials and different approaches to creating DNN modules.  The newest and easiest way to get started writing modules (IMO) can be found [here](http://dnnmodulecreator.codeplex.com/).